# Why a function work faster with full array than with empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, v8

I have two implements of function, that gets the last element of array.

```
function first(array) {
  var length = array ? array.length : 0;
  return length ? array[length - 1] : undefined;
}

function second(array) {
  return array ? array[array.length - 1] : undefined;
}
```

And second function work with full array faster than first, but slowly with empty. Why and how I can fix it?

Benchmark with full array: http://jsperf.com/lodash-f-last/

Benchmark with empty array:
http://jsperf.com/lodash-f-last/2

Comment: Your question will be more concise if you replace the words 'better' and 'bad' with what you mean. I am gathering you meant 'faster' and 'slower'?

Comment: I'm just curios about the second function. An empty array is still an array, right? That means `array ?` would be true, so array[-1] would be returned, or am I wrong?

Comment: @ElijahLynn oh, sorry, I updated question

Comment: @Doodlebunch Okay, checked it myself. An empty array is false in conditions, sorry.

Comment: Could it be because of branch prediction?

Comment: @Doodlebunch um, no - `if ([]) console.log('hi');` gives `hi`

Comment: @Doodlebunch Seems like empty is true: http://jsfiddle.net/ncwphdt4/

Comment: @eithedog Hm... okay, JavaScript and PHP seem to handle this different. In PHP an empty array is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your code to be fast you should never ever read out of bounds: V8  **deoptimizes** the code that does that.

In you `second` function you do precisely that - you read out of bounds. Instead do the bounds check before reading:

```js
function xlast(array) {
  return (array && array.length > 0) ? array[array.length - 1] 
                                     : undefined;
}
```

Comment: @PavelGatnar yeah can write that, but we are entering a microoptimization realm here. I doubt this "bit" will be noticable.

Comment: @PavelGatnar actually this version you currently have in your comment is unlikely to provide any benefit - first of all you can't do `array.length` before you check if `array` is defined and then modern engines are well capable of applying common-subexpression elimination (CSE) to `array.length` themselves.

Comment: sorry here is my corrected function: `function xlast(array, len) {return array && (len = array.length) ? array[--len] : undefined}`

Answer (score 3):

To me it seems that **second** function is **quicker with full array** because you don't have to do the `var length = array ? array.length : 0;` like in the first function, which saves you an extra trinary condition.

With an **empty array** however, the **second** function is **slower** since you are forced to do an `arr[-1]` (because empty array still provides true inside if) which is a getter function and in the first function the condition is `if (0)` which is false and you simply return undefined.

As for your second question - *how to fix it* - I assume this will do the trick since it will save you the getter function:

```
function second(array) {
  return array && array.length ? array[array.length - 1] : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of an empty array, it might be the cost of the array lookup, because your algorithms behave differently at zero length, note the control variable of the `?` operator:

```
function first(array) {
  var length = array ? array.length : 0;
  return length ? array[length - 1] : undefined;
}
```

returns undefined for [] **from evaluating the right side of the ?: construct**, because 0 evaluates to false.

On the other hand,

```
function second(array) {
  return array ? array[array.length - 1] : undefined;
}
```

returns undefined for [] **from evaluating array[-1]**, because [] evaluates to true.

In case of the full array, the second algo is trivially simpler.